# Python - Extract paragraph from text

Tags: python, regex

This is my first time posting so I apologize if I omit necessary information!

I am trying to extract a paragraph of text in Python that always follows a line starting with "Item 5.02". There is a line space between "Item 5.02" and the paragraph that I am trying to extract. I need the text between the "Item 5.02" line and the next section (in this case the next section starts at "Item 9.01"). Please let me know if I need to clarify anything. I have been tinkering with regular expressions but haven't had much luck. I'm pretty new to them. Thanks for the help!

I would like to extract the following:

```
    On September 29, 2015, AAR CORP. (the Company) announced that Michael J. Sharp was elected Chief Financial Officer of the Company on September 28, 2015, with such election to be effective on October 5, 2015. Mr. Sharp will replace John C. Fortson, who is resigning effective October 5, 2015 to take a Chief Financial Officer position with a non-aviation company. Mr. Sharp, 53, is a 19-veteran of the Company and will continue to serve as the Companys Vice President and Chief Accounting Officer. Mr. Sharp previously served as interim Chief Financial Officer of the Company from October 2012 to July 2013. Prior to joining the Company, Mr. Sharp worked in management positions with Kraft Foods and KPMG, LLP. As Chief Financial Officer of the Company, Mr. Sharp will receive the following compensation for the fiscal year ending May 31, 2016: an annual base salary of $400,000; an annual cash bonus opportunity equal to 70% of his annual base salary if certain performance goals are met at a target level; and total stock awards valued at $500,000 on the date of grant. Mr. Sharp continues to be eligible for other benefits provided to executive officers of the Company as described in the Companys proxy statement filed with the Securities and Exchange Commission on August 28, 2015. Mr. Sharp has a severance and change in control agreement with the Company (see Exhibit 10.10 to the Companys annual report on Form 10-K for the fiscal year ended May 31, 2001). A copy of the Companys press release announcing Mr. Sharps appointment is attached hereto as Exhibit 99.1 and is incorporated herein by reference.
```

From the below text:

```
    Item 5.02 Departure of Directors or Certain Officers; Election of Directors; Appointment of Certain Officers; Compensatory Arrangement of Certain Officers.

    On September 29, 2015, AAR CORP. (the Company) announced that Michael J. Sharp was elected Chief Financial Officer of the Company on September 28, 2015, with such election to be effective on October 5, 2015. Mr. Sharp will replace John C. Fortson, who is resigning effective October 5, 2015 to take a Chief Financial Officer position with a non-aviation company.

    Mr. Sharp, 53, is a 19-veteran of the Company and will continue to serve as the Companys Vice President and Chief Accounting Officer. Mr. Sharp previously served as interim Chief Financial Officer of the Company from October 2012 to July 2013. Prior to joining the Company, Mr. Sharp worked in management positions with Kraft Foods and KPMG, LLP.

    As Chief Financial Officer of the Company, Mr. Sharp will receive the following compensation for the fiscal year ending May 31, 2016: an annual base salary of $400,000; an annual cash bonus opportunity equal to 70% of his annual base salary if certain performance goals are met at a target level; and total stock awards valued at $500,000 on the date of grant. Mr. Sharp continues to be eligible for other benefits provided to executive officers of the Company as described in the Companys proxy statement filed with the Securities and Exchange Commission on August 28, 2015. Mr. Sharp has a severance and change in control agreement with the Company (see Exhibit 10.10 to the Companys annual report on Form 10-K for the fiscal year ended May 31, 2001).

    A copy of the Companys press release announcing Mr. Sharps appointment is attached hereto as Exhibit 99.1 and is incorporated herein by reference.

    Item 9.01 Financial Statements and Exhibits.
```

Comment: Is your identifier really "Item 5.02" or is this just an example?

Comment: The identifier will always be "Item 5.02"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split it by double newlines, find the piece which contains Item 5.02, then take the next one:

```
def extractPassage(text):
    lines = text.split("\n\n")
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith("Item 5.02"):
            return lines[i+1]
    raise Exception("No line found starting with Item 5.02")
```

I can't tell from the post formatting if there are any tabs or spaces before Item 5.02 on that line. If so, include them in the startswith call.

To get all text between 5.02 and 9.01, we can append lines to a string, starting after the one starting with 5.02, and ending when we see 9.01:

```
def extractPassage(text):
    lines = text.split("\n\n")
    output = ""
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith("Item 5.02"):
            j = i+1
            take_line = lines[j]
            while not take_line.startswith("Item 9.01"):
                output += take_line
                j += 1
                take_line = lines[j]
            return output
    raise Exception("No line found starting with Item 5.02")
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is a good start. Quick question-- how do I manipulate it so that it will grab all text between the "Item 5.02" line and another phrase? In this instance, I want all text between the line starting with "Item 5.02", and the line starting with "Item 9.01"? It's currently only grabbing the first sentence.

Comment: Edited to include getting all between the matching lines

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match the word *Item* followed by a space, one number, one period, and then two more numbers.

```
import re
re.split('Item \d\.\d\d', text)
```

To explain the regex: `\d` will match any number, and then to match a period we have to escape the period using `\.`.

If you would rather accept either 1 or 2 digits after the period, you would use the regex `'Item \d\.\d{1,2}'`